# MYSQL MONTHNAME() function returns Blob

Tags: mysql

Could some body help me to find the month name in MYSQL. I have read many post related to `MONTHNAME()` method in SO, but not find my answer.

My code sample :-

```
   select MONTHNAME(now())as MONTTH; 

   select MONTHNAME(str_to_date(6,'%m'))as MONTTH
```

Both are return `BLOB` data. Why it return `BLOB`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to work fine on my installation of mysql.

Comment: But not working on my system.

Comment: A `how` will help me too. :) (For future references)

Comment: Total query is :-  select convert(MONTHNAME(now()) USING latin1)as MONTTH

Comment: maybe the error is in the workbench, can you try from console?

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT MONTH(name) FROM tablename;
```

will select the month if that's what you are meaning.

Comment: The question is about `MONTHNAME`, not `MONTH`.